# Mocha with import.meta

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, vite

I would like to implement mocha and chai as my testing library (for unit tests only). The project is all in typescript and consists of a server bundle, and nested within there is a client bundle which is managed with Vite.
As I am sure you are aware, Vite uses the import.meta object for a bunch of stuff, like env variables, mode, etc. The issue I am having is that when I try to run the tests I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module`.

I can use mocharc to ignore a subdirectory, but it doesn't work for a single file in a shared directory (ie. offending import.meta file lives in the same directory as other files I do want to test). So, one solution is to move that one file out to one side, which is doable but a bit ugly.
I have already had a pretty good search around for solutions but as yet am unable to find anything clean enough to justify adding in. I would like to avoid adding babel to the bundle if I can, but I know that it might be able to help in this instance.

Of course, I could use vitest for the whole project, but I'd like to try and meet requirements first if possible. Does anyone have a tried and tested/elegant solution they could share?